# How to select values 2+ after any number in a list?

Tags: list, groovy

Is there any way to select the second, third (etc) value from a value in a list in Groovy? I'm still very new to programming in general and am just wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

For example, if I have the list

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to select the next two values after each value using a for loop:

```
for 1: (1, 2, 3)
for 2: (2, 3, 4)
```

...and so on.

Is that easily possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using groovy 1.8.1 or later, you can use the [take](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#take%28int%29) and [drop](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#drop%28int%29) methods:

```
def foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
foo.size().times { i ->
    println foo.drop(i).take(3)
}
```

This will result in

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6]
[6]
```

If you want the iteration to stop at the last group of three, try something like this:

```
def foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
if (foo.size() > 2) {
    (foo.size() - 2).times { i ->
        println foo.drop(i).take(3)
    }    
}
```

which gives

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I'm trying to work through this logically in my head. The code works...

Just want to clarify that I know what is happening here.

So, foo.size() returns an integer as large as the list, and times makes it run that many times. Then for each i in foo, "drop" drops off the first "i" values of the array and takes the next three values and prints them in a list? Brilliant solution, let me know if that's not quite what's happening though. :P

Comment: @Ben that's exactly what it does :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using Groovy 1.8.1+, then you can acheive a similar result by writing a function like so:

```
List split( List foo, int size ) {
  (0..foo.size()-size).collect { foo[ it..it+size-1 ] }
}
```

Then, you can call this like:

```
split( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3 )
```

to print

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you! It's always good to have more than one way of doing things under my belt.